# Converting Large Dollar Values in C#

Tags: c#, floating-point

I have an application that manages project costs from as little as a million to billions of dollars.  Initially, users enter an estimate of the project: called an 'appropriation amount'.

**The Issue Is:**
The original value is not converting as expected.  Some examples include:

They enter-in: 111,222,333
It converts to: 111,222,336

They enter-in: 111,222,333,444
It converts to: 111,222,333,440

**The Problem Occurrs Here:**
The issue arises upon conversion in the following line of code...

```
project.AppropriationAmount = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAppropriationDollars.Text)) ? Convert.ToSingle(txtAppropriationDollars.Text) : 0;
```

**NOTES:**
`project.AppropriationAmount` is a `float`.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Any job openings?  I see an opportunity.

Comment: I doubt this is the issue... but why are you using Convert? Just use `Single.Parse()` or `Single.TryParse()`. You don't want to convert the value, you just want to parse it.

Comment: 'Single.TryParse()' results in a scientific-notation value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `decimal` instead of `float` for money.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx):

> The decimal keyword indicates a 128-bit data type. Compared to
>   floating-point types, the decimal type has more precision and a
>   smaller range, which makes it appropriate for financial and monetary
>   calculations.

Using `Convert.ToDecimal(..)` and assigning to a `decimal` variable yielded the expected (correct) results for your examples.

Comment: I guess the question becomes, is a Decimal still appropriate for very large numbers like: 111,222,333,444?

Comment: @PrisonerZERO: Absolutely. Decimal handles up to 28 digits.